# Paying Credit Card statement amount in full on due date and using it in the same day

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, payment, balance

I have this question. I paid my Credit Card statement amount yesterday in full (which I always do), on due date. Its an online transfer. Immediately after an hour (before the transaction is even processed), I used the Credit Card for other purchases. Would this show up as unpaid balance?

Another question, I noticed that paying ON time has major impact than paying IN time (leaving 0 balance). I have been paying in time full amount almost leaving no balance on the due date. The credit score stagnated long back and did not improve. However, for the past two months I am paying ON time, that increased my credit score by 10pts. Why is that so?

Answer (score 8):

Your billing cycle and due date are not the same thing. Your billing cycle ends well before the due date. So no, that extra charge would not count as unpaid.

Another thing to note: Even if you pay in full by the due date, that doesn't mean your credit report will show a zero balance. When the balance is reported [isn't that simple](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/day-report-balance-data-bureaus-1586.php).

If you are that concerned about your credit balances affecting your credit (usually not worth it), then just keep your balance below 30% of the credit limit at all times.

Comment: Yes, I keep my overall balance below 20%. But the due date thingy is what I could not my wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

Your extra charge shouldn't show as unpaid, since you had paid the card already. I'm not sure about the second half of your question but it's a really interesting subject that I had never really thought of before. I'm going to have to run a little test on my own, to see how on time vs. in time, impacts my own credit.